# Can't creatw WIN10 boot usb using WINUSB

Tags: windows, winusb

Hope someone can help me. I get the following error meassage:

```
Installation failed !

Exit code: 256

Log:

Formating device...

Mounting...

mount: /dev/loop0 is write-protected, mounting read-only

Copying...

Installing grub...

Installing for x86_64-efi platform.

grub-install: fejl: /media/winusb_target_1450615156_3001 doesn't look like an EFI partition.

Error occured !

Syncing...

/usr/bin/winusb: linje 78:  7310 Termineret              while true; do
    sleep 0.05; echo 'pulse';
done
Cleaning...
/usr/bin/winusb: linje 78:  7446 Termineret 
             while true; do
    sleep 0.05; echo 'pulse';

done

Umounting and removing '/media/winusb_iso_1450615156_3001'...

Umounting and removing '/media/winusb_target_1450615156_3001'...
```

Comment: NO NEED TO SHOUT BUDDY

Comment: What have I done ?

Comment: How did you install WinUSB?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, unfortunately Windows is off-topic please see [help/on-topic] I would suggest moving your question to (http://superuser.com/)

Comment: @DnrDevil Why is it off-topic? I think he tries to create a Windows bootable USB using Ubuntu.

Comment: Doesn't seem this way from text however you may be right in any case winusb is not recommend to use in Linux by Windows

Comment: @kalpetros, i do not remember. Does it need to be installed in a specific way ?

Comment: Read [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/489556/145133). It's a pretty straightforward procedure. Just add the ppa and install WinUSB. Then use a 8GB or more flash drive and click install. It should work.

Comment: Ok so the problem here is this: `doesn't look like an EFI partition`. WinUSB only creates MBR bootable USB drives. I think there is a workaround to this by changing the method that WinUSB is using to install GRUB.

Answer (score 0):

WinUSB functions require Windows XP or later. You can use these functions in your C/C++ application to communicate with your USB device. Microsoft does not provide a managed API for WinUSB.